# Match an exact keyword by using query formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to match an exact keyword by using query formula ?

My table looks like this

Col B---------------------Col S

abc (Car A) ----------------5

defghi (Car)----------------3

jklmn-----------------------7

etc...

When i use this formula ((see below) , it returns me 8. But i would like to have 3 as result as i'm trying to match the exact *Car* keyword.

query(A8:S,"select SUM(S) where B MATCHES '.*Car.*' label SUM(S)' '",0)

Can someone help me with that please ?

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
=QUERY(A8:S, "select sum(S) where B matches '.+\(Car\)' label sum(S)''", )
```

[image]

but try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(S8:S*REGEXMATCH(B8:B, "Car\)"))
```

[image]